# How many options are there to get the product image url in magento?

Tags: image, magento, url

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(90, 130, false, true);
```

This gets the image url and I believe it will resize the image to 90X130, does any know the meaning of the third and fourth parameters? Where is the code that does the actual resize and where will it save the resized image?

I can also get the image url from the lines below, is there any other ways to get the image url for image size of thumb, small, large?

```
$product->getImageUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Code that does the actual resize is located at

```
{Magento Directory}\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Image.php
```

check **setBaseFile** function for process

Other ways to get the image url for image size of thumbnail, small_image,image.

// image url

```
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
```

// small image url

```
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image');
```

// thumbnail image url

```
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail');
```